# Data passing between Objects without introducing tight coupling?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, delegates

I am working with delegate, datasource pattern to achieve lean View Controller in iOS, I did separated DataSource and Delegate into separate objects.

> This code can be executed in playground

```
// Calender Delegate
protocol CalenderDelegate: class{
    func calender(_ calender: Calender, willDisplay year:Int)
    func calender(_ calender: Calender, didSelect date: Date)
    func calenderShouldChange(_ calender: Calender) -> Bool
}

// Calender DataSource

protocol CalenderDataSource{
    func calender(_ calender: Calender, eventsFor date: Date) -> [String]
    func calender(_ calender: Calender, add event: String, to date: Date)
}

// Calander Object

class Calender{
    weak var delegate: CalenderDelegate?
    var dataSource: CalenderDataSource?
    var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    var currentYear: Int = 2018

    func changeDate(to date: Date){
        self.selectedDate = date
        delegate?.calender(self, didSelect: date)
        if let items = dataSource?.calender(self, eventsFor: date){
            print("Events for \(date) are")
            items.forEach{print($0)}
        }
        else{
            print("This is a rest day not event hurrrhhhhaaa!")
        }
    }

    func changeYear(to year: Int) {
        if delegate?.calenderShouldChange(self) ?? true{
            delegate?.calender(self, willDisplay: year)
            self.currentYear = year
            print(year)
        }
    }


    func add(event: String){
        dataSource?.calender(self, add: event, to: selectedDate)
    }
}

// Datasource

class RemindersCalenderDataSource: CalenderDataSource{

    func calender(_ calender: Calender, eventsFor date: Date) -> [String] {
        return ["Event 1","Event 2","Event 3","Event 4","Event 4"]
    }
    func calender(_ calender: Calender, add event: String, to date: Date) {
        print("Events for date are \(event) \(date).")
    }
}
protocol ReminderPresenting {
    func yearChanged(to year: Int)
}

// Delegate
class RemindersCalenderDelegate: CalenderDelegate{

    var parentController: ReminderPresenting?

    func calender(_ calender: Calender, willDisplay year: Int) {
        self.parentController?.yearChanged(to: year)
        // self.title = "Year: \(year)"

    }
    func calender(_ calender: Calender, didSelect date: Date) {
        print("You selected date \(date)")
    }
    func calenderShouldChange(_ calender: Calender) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

//Gernal Object like ViewController
class Reminders: ReminderPresenting{
    var title = "Year: 2200"
    var calender = Calender()

    init() {
        calender.delegate = RemindersCalenderDelegate()
        calender.dataSource = RemindersCalenderDataSource()
    }
    func yearChanged(to year: Int) {
        self.title = "Year: \(year)"
        print(self.title)
    }
}
```

**My question is**

How to set the title property of Reminders class from  RemindersCalenderDelegate's willDisplay method without creating high coupling in both objects.

**This solution is not accepted**

```
// In RemindersCalenderDelegate 
var parentController: Reminders?

func calendar(_ calendar: Calendar, willDisplay year: Int) {
    parentController?.title = "Year: \(year)"
}
```

> Example is taken from: Paul Hudson. “Swift Design Patterns.” Book.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want to introduce one-way communication without tight coupling, you can use closures to pass the information back in a generic fashion, and give the consumer control over tying the data to its local controls.

Going through what you have, I think this is the right relationship. You could also typealias the callback type if it helps keep your code tidy.

```
class RemindersCalenderDelegate: CalenderDelegate{

    let yearSelectionCallback: (Int) -> ()

    init(yearSelectionCallback: (Int) -> ()) {
        self.yearSelectionCallback = yearSelectioncallback
    }

    func calender(_ calender: Calender, willDisplay year: Int) {
        yearSelectionCallback(year)
    }
    func calender(_ calender: Calender, didSelect date: Date) {
        print("You selected date \(date)")
    }
    func calenderShouldChange(_ calender: Calender) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class Reminders: ReminderPresenting{
    var title = "Year: 2200"
    var calender = Calender()

    init() {
       calender.delegate = RemindersCalenderDelegate(yearChangedCallback: {
           [weak self]
           year in
           self?.yearChanged(to: year)
       })
       calender.dataSource = RemindersCalenderDataSource()
    }

    func yearChanged(to year: Int) {
       self.title = "Year: \(year)"
       print(self.title)
    }
}
```

Of course, keep in mind that this keeps RemindersCalendarDelegate from knowing about ReminderPresenting, but doesn't help keep ReminderPresenting implementers know about RemindersCalendarDelegate's implementation.

To avoid that, maybe consider adopting a factory pattern who's sole job it is to know about those couplings! This would allow the ReminderPresenting and the RemindersCalendar to go through life having no need to know the other exists.

Comment: Thank You for pointing to this approach? Just one thing , if there is more then 1 occasion to pass data , passing all closures in init will be messy, any suggestion on it?